# ASP.Net + JQuery Tabs: Using the Cookie Option Breaks my GUI 

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, cookies

I've got a tabbed GUI on a webpage using:

- JQuery 1.4.2
- JQuery-UI 1.8.9  (full download)

The IDs for the 'pane' divs are GUIDs of domain objects in a database. Everything works as it should.

But when I include the `cookie` option in the function call on

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$("#tabs").tabs(); //Without tabs works fine

    $("#tabs").tabs({    //This call with cookie option breaks everything.
        cookie: {
            expires: 1
        }
    });
});
```

By 'breaks' I mean - the contents of my final tab (which includes a 'submit' button) ends up being displayed at the bottom of every tabbed page although the tab itself looks fine. None of the tabs open the corresponding pane when clicked, but I can see the correct tab id in the address bar on the browser when I click a tab.

I've compared the source of both pages (with and without the `cookie` option) and they are *identical* apart from the call to the JQuery `tab` function.

But the Javascript console reports an error:

```
cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
```

<strike>Is there something else I need to do to get this to work? The documentation suggests not ...</strike>

I've inluded the cookies plugin as suggested by Nalum, but this hasn't solved the problem.

Drilling into `jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js` gets me the offending bit of code:

```
return d.cookie.apply(null,[b].concat(d.makeArray(arguments ...
```

This code seems to be expecting `[b]` to be something like `ui-tabs-1` which is the way in which the tabs are IDed if you add tabs via the `tabs.add(...)` function. And of course I don't add my tabs this way - all my tabs have GUID IDs which are related to elements which come from a DB and are output by a Repeater control.

Some HTML below for reference:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>            
        <li>
            <a href='#TabDiv471de30d-aaec-4485-8a50-1b2fdbc58053'>
                Tab A
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='#TabDiv951e2fee-9272-4a8c-becb-3f3a07770347'>
                Tab B
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id='TabDiv471de30d-aaec-4485-8a50-1b2fdbc58053'>
        This is Pane A
    </div>
    <div id='TabDiv951e2fee-9272-4a8c-becb-3f3a07770347'>
        This is Pane B
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [jQuery UI Docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-cookie), note: **Requires cookie plugin.**

> Store the latest selected tab in a
>   cookie. The cookie is then used to
>   determine the initially selected tab
>   if the selected option is not defined.
>   **Requires cookie plugin.** The object
>   needs to have key/value pairs of the
>   form the cookie plugin expects as
>   options. Available options (example):
>   { expires: 7, path: '/', domain:
>   'jquery.com', secure: true }. Since
>   jQuery UI 1.7 it is also possible to
>   define the cookie name being used via
>   name property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I downloaded jquery-cookies.js from http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie and have included it in my page. It doesn't seem to have made any difference - is there something else I need to do to get it working?

Comment: The tabs now switch correctly (many thanks) but some of them don't show their content - its all hidden. 

Not sure if this is related to me updating the jquery ui css sheet to the latest version.

Comment: Are you still having issues with the content not displaying?